# Crear contenido html de acuerdo a base de datos con JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Estoy desarrollando un sistema para una cervezeria y tiene dos tipos de envases: medio y cuarto. ¿Pero que sucederia si en el futuro quiere agregar el entero(1 litro)? En la ventana de venta tiene que aparecer este tipo de envase. lo mismo puede ocurrir en cualquier sistema ya que todas las organizaciones varian.

Entonces queria consultarles cual es la forma mas correcta o por lo menos algun metodo para crear dinamicamente el contenido html y poder procesarlo.

Es decir deberia tener un proceso AJAX donde consultaria la lista de envases de una tabla de bd obviamente. Y luego debo crear un input o lo que necesite por cada resultado con un id distinto. Es correcto?
Por ejemplo, el siguiente codigo lo tengo en el click de un boton, en un formulario donde se ingresa una provision de mercaderia, y luego aparecen las 3 medidas para actualizar su precio.

```js
$.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/stock/procesostock.php",
                data:{"accion":accion,"idprod":idprod,"barril":barril,"precio":precio},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
               
                    $("#prod").val("");
                    $("#prov").val("");
                    $("#cant").val("");
                    $("#gasto").val("");
                    alert("Operacion realizada con exito");
                    
                        
                    
                    var contenido= '<div class="row" id="precios">'+
           '<div class="col-sm-2"><label>PRECIO FINAL 1/4</label></div>'+
  
    '<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="preciocuarto" placeholder="1/4 l."/>'+
      '</div><div class="col-sm-2"><label>PRECIO FINAL 1/2</label></div>'+
  
    '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
     '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="preciomedio" placeholder="1/2 l."/>'+
       '</div><div class="col-sm-2"><label>PRECIO FINAL 1</label></div>'+
  
   ' <div class="col-sm-2">'+
     ' <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio1" placeholder="1l"/>'+
       '</div><div class="col-sm-2"><label>PRECIO ENVASE</label></div>'+
  
    '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
     ' <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precioentero" placeholder="barril"/>'+
      ' </div> <input type="button" id="actprecio" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary" /></div>'
                    $(contenido).appendTo("#grupo");
                    $("#produ").attr("disabled",true);
                  $("#actprecio").click(function(){
                    
                var preciocuarto=$("#preciocuarto").val();
                var preciomedio=$("#preciomedio").val();
                var precioentero=$("#precio1").val();
                var preciouno=$("#precioentero").val();
                if( preciocuarto=="" || preciomedio=="" || precioentero=="" || preciouno==""){
                    alert("complete todos los campos");
                }else{
                    
                    
                
                $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/stock/procesostock.php",
       data:{"accion":"actualizar","idprodu":idprod,"preciocuarto":preciocuarto,"preciomedio":preciomedio,"preciouno":precioentero,"entero":preciouno},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
           alert("actualizacion exitosa");
       window.location.href="index.php?controller=stock&action=indexb";
            }
         });}
         });
           }  
  }); } });
```

Como veran creo una variable con el contenido html.
Es decir deberia hacer una llamada ajax para saber que tipos de envases hay, y crear contenido html por cada uno?

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado ambigua y está sujeta a muchas respuestas, ya que se desconocen muchas cosas de lo que estás intentando. Lo apropiado sería que nos pusieran código de lo que estás intentando hacer. Entiendo que lo que buscas es que se te oriente un poco para saber por donde empezar, pero este tipo de preguntas no suele ser bien aceptada y es muy posible que se te puntue negativamente o que tu pregunta quede sin responder. Podrías ponernos por ejemplo, el HTML en el que deseas mostrar ese listado de cervezas para la venta (que creo que es lo estás queriendo hacer).

Comment: Acabo de editar..gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver... tu pregunta no alude a un problema específico, y por tanto debiera llamarse:

> Cuál es la lógica de un flujo donde el frontend tiene que desplegar resultados dinámicos que se adapten si yo agrego elementos en la base de datos".

O bien

> Qué algoritmo se puede usar para representar en el frontend una respuesta del backend cuyos atributos pueden ir cambiando en el tiempo

Esta pregunta es un poco más contestable, porque aplica a todos los lenguajes de backend, conectados a cualquier base de datos, y usando cualquier framework de frontend (o ninguno).

**Entonces:**

La lógica para esta clase de flujo es diseñar el front diciéndole: "Itera sobre el bucle tantas veces como registros te mande el backend".

Y al backend: "Manda tantos registros como tipos distintos de categorías quieras imprimir".

En tu ejemplo, tienes una cervecería y tu criterio para distinguir es el tamaño del envase. Entonces en tu backend ejecutas una query del tipo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre, precio FROM producto
```

Y devuelves un array en formato JSON que contiene:

```
[{
    "nombre":"producto1",
    "precio":10
},{
    "nombre":"producto2",
    "precio":20
},{
    "nombre":"producto3",
    "precio":30
}];
```

Pensemos que el frontend almacena esos datos en una variable `respuesta`, y cada respuesta genera un bloque HTML dentro de un contenedor con id `#resultado`. Entonces, de nuevo en términos generales, el front pondría

```
foreEach(respuesta, function(producto) {
   var bloque=jQuery('<div class="producto">');
   bloque.append('<div class="nombre">'+producto.nombre+'</div>');
   bloque.append('<div class="precio">'+producto.precio+'</div>');

   bloque.appendTo('#resultado');
});
```

**Datos anidados**

Mirando tu código, lo que quieres es tener para el mismo producto, un subcriterio de división. **No tiene sentido que cada variante de producto implique crear columnas adicionales en la tabla**. El esquema de la base de datos debiera estar pensado para que puedas añadir infinitas combinaciones de producto y tamaño simplemente añadiendo filas.

Entonces el backend adaptaría la query más o menos como sigue:

```
-- postgres
SELECT nombre, json_agg(envase), avg(precio) as precio FROM producto group by nombre

-- mysql
SELECT nombre, JSON_ARRAYAGG(envase), avg(precio) as precio FROM producto group by nombre
```

Y la respuesta del backend podría ser:

```
[{
    "nombre":"cerveza1",
    "precio":10,
    "envases":["medio litro", "litro", "pitcher", "pecera", "barril"]
},{
    "nombre":"cerveza2",
    "precio":20,
    "envases":["medio litro", "litro", "pitcher", "pecera", "barril"]
},{
    "nombre":"cerveza3",
    "precio":30
    "envases":["medio litro", "litro", "pitcher", "pecera", "barril"]
}];
```

De nuevo, la lógica se repite, el backend te envía un array que contiene arrays. Siempre que trabajes con arrays conoces el largo de éste (propiedad `length`) y puedes usarla para iterar añadiendo elementos a tu bucle.

En el caso particular tu ejemplo, **éste no es un buen enfoque** porque los atributos variables se han diagramado como columnas. y como el espacio del browser a lo ancho es un bien escaso (a diferencia del alto, nadie acostumbra a hacer scroll hacia el lado), diagramar con columnas variables no es un camino viable.

Podrías en cambio estudiar diagramar con tarjetas. Me explico: Cada producto es una tarjeta que ocupa un tercio del ancho del contenedor. Puede tener N tipos de envase, pero sabes que tiene un nombre, un precio promedio y una foto (por ejemplo). Entonces el cuerpo de tu tarjeta tiene como diagramación fija **los datos que sí tienes estandarizados**, y como pie, en un contenedor con espacio holgado, **los datos que pueden ir variando ya sea en el tiempo o entre los productos** los tamaños de envase como tabs, o cuadritos, o chips.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Digamos, tienes que **basarte** en lo que puedes dar por seguro y **manejar** lo que puede ser variable. En este caso, sí hay N cervezas pero pero no hay problema con que cada cerveza ocupe un tercio de la pantalla, si total se van a ir ordenando en líneas de a tres.

En cambio, si cada cerveza tiene un elemento hijo de largo variable,o varios atributos custom, tienes que manejar ese caso con alguna lógica de diagramación (en la imagen de arriba, los chips podrían ocupar un cuarto de la tarjeta e irse ordenando en filas de 4).

En el fondo, adaptas tu diagramación a la forma como sabes que cambiarán tus datos.

Si el proceso de compra implica configurar cuántas unidades quieres y de qué tamaño, la base de cada card tiene un input para la cantidad de unidades y sólo puedes activar un chip a la vez. El precio del carrito cambia según tus acciones en cada tarjeta. Ojo que para esto, el subcriterio debe ser un array de objetos con atributos "tamaño" y "precio". Eso es particular para tu flujo cada uno lo tendrá que adaptar a cómo más le sirva.

**Finalmente:**

Para ir todavía más allá, y esto es irse al extremo, pensemos que tienes un marketplace como AliExpress. Cada producto tiene o puede tener atributos distintos.

- Si vendes un pantalón éste tiene atributos  `color` y `tamaño`.

  - `color` es un array de 10 colores.
  - `tamaño` es un array de 6 tamaños.
- Si vendes una tarjeta de memoria microSD esta tiene sólo el atributo `capacidad` (16, 32 y 64 GB)
- Un tercer producto puede no tener atributos ni variaciones
- Un cuarto producto puede tener muchos atributos y entre éstos muchas variaciones.

En este caso, la base de datos tendría una tupla de tres niveles

```
producto | atributo  | valor | precio
---------------------------------------
vestido  | color     | rojo  | 10
vestido  | color     | azul  | 10
microsd  | capacidad | 16GB  | 20  <--- mala compra, conviene el de 32
microsd  | capacidad | 32GB  | 25
```

Pero ya en ese escenario, no sería sano meter todo en la misma tabla y habría que rediseñar la base de datos en tercera forma normal. Esto sólo lo planteé como el ejemplo más elaborado y no vale la pena entrar en detalle.

Answer (score 0):

No sé como tienes organizada tu **DB**, pero supongo que cada cerveza puede ser vendida en uno o más de los formatos de capacidad (1/4, 1/2 y 1/1) y que estos dependen del fabricante. Yo lo que haría sería tener en mi tabla "Cervezas" (supongo que tendrás una para almacenar los datos de cada cerveza) un campo por cada uno de los formatos de medida en los que se comercialice y valorarlo en "0" si no se comercializa en ese formato y en "1" si sí que lo hace.

Luego a la hora de pintar el **HTML** de tu vista, en el bucle que recorre cada cerveza para pintarla, comprobar los valores de estos campos y construir los **option** de tu **select** en base a ello.

Todo esto hablando desde hipotéticos, porque como te dije, hay información de la que carezco para afinar más.

Realmente no te haría falta una llamada **AJAX** para hacer esto, puesto que no vas a generar contenido dinamicamente, si no que en el momento de pintar el **HTML** ya dispones de todos los datos necesarios para saber los formatos de medida en los que se vende cada una de las cervezas.

**EDIT**

Acabo de leer que lo que haces al seleccionar un valor para el formato de medida de la cerveza es actualizar el precio de la compra. Ahí si que se usaría una llamada **AJAX** para preguntar en tu **DB** el precio de ese formato de medida específico.

Esto podrías hacerlo con una función `change()` de **Jquery**, para lanzar la consulta dependiendo del **option** que elija el usuario.

Creo que no me dejo nada en el tintero y espero que te sirva para orientar un poco tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Claro la logica es la misma para distintos casos ya que muchas cosas son variables.
En esta cervezeria se venden esas medidas desde barriles que estan en canillas, y el dia de mañana pueden haber mas o menos canillas.

Entonces con Bootstrap cree un panel, o lo que amenadiel llamo tarjetitas, y con poner 3 por fila (3 td por tr) es suficiente para el espacio que ocupa.

Entonces deberia dividir por 3, si hay 7 canillas son dos filas de 3 y una fila con una.
Pero en bootstrap el ancho debe sumar 12, entonces con:

```
'<div class="col-sm-4" >
```

Ya especifico que caben 3, es genial!!

```js
$.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"lcanillas"},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
         console.log(data);
                   $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, item) {
         var contenido='<div class="col-sm-4" > '+
         '<div class="panel panel-danger">'+
          '<div class="panel-heading">CANILLA '+item.idcanilla+'</div>'+
          '<div class="panel-body">'+
        '<table class="canilla">'+
   ' <thead>'+
    '<th></th>'+
    '<th>Valor</th>'+
    '<th>Accion</th>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Estado</td>'+
    '<td>60 lts</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Cuarto</td>'+
    '<td>$10</td>'+
    +'<td><input type="button" id="Confirmar" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>'
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Medio</td>'+
    '<td>$15</td>'
    +'<td><input type="button" id="Confirmar" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>'
   ' </tr>'+
   ' </tbody>'+
  '</table>'+
      '     </div></div></div> ' +
      '  </div>';
      $(contenido).appendTo("#canilla1");
                });

                }
 
});
```

Comment: Más o menos. Ya es un avance. Al menos implementaste la parte que la unidad padre es un producto, y cada producto tiene un ancho fijo, y que luego sus atributos van desglosándose hacia abajo. Supongo que en realidad los precios y tamaños que tienes en duro los vas a tomar de la respuesta Ajax